# ExecuteReader return just "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader" in text box

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have problem with this code and I don't know why that is.

Code:

```
SqlConnection getconn = new SqlConnection(somthing secured);              
string sql = "select  pk_stu_id , stu_name   from MRK , STU , LSN where fk_stu_id = pk_stu_id and fk_lsn_id = pk_lsn_id AND pk_lsn_id="
      + int.Parse(textBoxSearchStudentID.Text)
      + " and pk_stu_id="
      + int.Parse(textBoxSearchLessonID.Text); 



SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, getconn);
getconn.Open();
SqlDataReader result  = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (result.Read())
{
    textBoxDataSend.Text = string.Empty;
    textBoxDataSend.Text = result.ToString();
}
getconn.Close();
```

But it just always returns: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader".

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: are you able to run it now?

Comment: yes bro it works.thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** you are directly assigning `SqlDataReader` obect to your `TextBox`.

**Solution :** you need to access the required `columns` returned by your `query` using `SqlDataReader` object by providing either by column `name` or column `index`.

Replace this:

```
textBoxDataSend.Text = result.ToString();
```

with this:

```
textBoxDataSend.Text = result["stu_name"].ToString();//or you can give any other column name here
```

Answer (score 0):

Any `object` if `ToString()` is used for that will give you what kind of `object` it is, unless `ToString()` is `override` specifically inside the `class`.